# How To Alter Nodequeue or EntityQueue search Autocomplete

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes, entities

I want to use nodequeue or entityqueue in Drupal 7 and want the autocomplete search for a given queue to use a custom field other than the node title.

Is there a way to do this without hacking the modules? I want the nodequeue autocomplete to work off of a speaker name, rather than the nodes title presay.

I see Nodequeue issues that add query tags to make the query modifiable by developers but all the issues are 2+ years old and none are committed:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2231793#comment-8725319
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2446711